# Is there a problem with dialog::backdrop in Vue3?

Tags: dialog, vuejs3

In Vue3 `<dialog>` opens as expected using `ref`.
However, I can't seem to control the dialog::backdrop property. [Here's the reproduction link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8p1au4?file=src%2FApp.vue).
Also, when pressing the `Esc` key it doesn't close the dialog.
It [works as expected in vanilla js](https://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/abQxQJM).

Any ideas as to why this happens, or how to fix it? Ideally I'd like to take advantage of the native behaviours as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::backdrop` only shows for dialogs when they are opened with `showModal()` (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop)), but you are using `show()`. When I change it in the stackblitz, it works as expected:

```js
function showDialog() {
  dialog.value.showModal();
}
```

Comment: Lol, it's always a typo for me man. Thank you!

Comment: oh do I know about it... glad that it's working!